# Product image not showing on product page WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

my product images are not showing on the product pages, I coded it away in functions.php and now I want it to display so I removed the code I've made but now the images are not coming back! Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can get product image using this code

```
<?php echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail(); ?>
```

But remember this itself is inside an image tag so donot use this as src of image tag, rather inside a div.

Comment: where do I need to place this code? (which file)

Comment: products.php or product.php file depending on your naming. This will echo image tag with src.